# What does .apply do for a keras layer? Is there a way to omit it or any other alternative way to get the same output without using .apply?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, tf.keras

Can someone explain what `.apply(input_feature)` actually does?

```
VFE_1_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, tf.nn.relu)
vfe_1_out = VFE_1_layer.apply(feature)
```

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation for it... and the [source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/03d890dfae5cd71da88dcd003be95d60976978db/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py#L1067) doesn't mention `.apply`, either.

Comment: Yes. I couln't find anything in documentation either. I was just going through a research code and couldn't understand what it actually is doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Layer.apply` is deprecated. The recommended alternative is to use `Layer.__call__` instead (which can be done by simply *calling*):

```
dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu')
new_feature = dense(feature)
```

This is known as the **Functional API** style.

---

You can find the deprecation notice [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e31577598b02caf6a5bf6ebff0a83d35c4739233/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L2214):

```
class Layer:
  ...

  @deprecation.deprecated(
      date=None, instructions='Please use `layer.__call__` method instead.')
  @doc_controls.do_not_doc_inheritable
  def apply(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs):
    """Deprecated, do NOT use!

    This is an alias of `self.__call__`.

    Arguments:
      inputs: Input tensor(s).
      *args: additional positional arguments to be passed to `self.call`.
      **kwargs: additional keyword arguments to be passed to `self.call`.

    Returns:
      Output tensor(s).
    """
    return self.__call__(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you. Got it now